# how to add list column values to workflow email?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a calendar list and I added several text box column values. I am using a customized workflow created in SharePoint Designer 2010 to send an email when there is a new event is added.

I want to add the values of all the columns of the list to this email. How can I do that? I was able to get Name of the event, End time and Start time by using `[%Current Item: Name of Event%]` and so on. But how can I get the other column values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to close SPD and clear its cahce before adding. The cache is located here:

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

**UPDATE1:** It has become much clear after comments.
The cause of your issue is the fact that you added fields to a list, but not to content type. As your workflow is reusable it only "can see" fields that are in content type it is associated with. Whereas list workflows can see fields which are in the list.

**So in your case I can see two solutions:**

a) create your own content type derived from Event (MyEvent for instance) and add necessary field there. In such a case you can create reusable workflow associated with this content type and all the fields will be visible.

b) create list workflow. In such a case you will be able to use all the fields which are in the list.

**UPDATE2:** As you use standard reusable workflow, you can use Solution a). For that first you have to create Content Type derived from Event. You can do it as follows:
[image]
[image]

After that create some Site column (Select Site Columns in the left panel and press New Column). After creating site column don't forget to press Save button.
Now you should add your site column to new content type:

[image]

That is alomost all. Now you have to go Copy/Modify reusable Approval workflow and select your new MyEvent content type for that.

[image]

Now you should be able to have access to all the columns in your MyEvent content type!

Comment: I want to get the column names from a list. May I know How can clearing the columns would help? I was able to add fields of "Event" content type but I added 3 more fields to the event content type for one list. I want to display those column values in workflow email

Comment: Not clearing of columns, but clearing of cache (probably SPD remembered the previous state).

Comment: What type of workflow do you have? List or Reusable?

Comment: @ MikhailSP I have reusable workflow.

Comment: Are sure that you added columns to the content type, but not to list? You can check it using SPD (select Content Types in the left panel).

Comment: No, I added columns to the list. Not to the content type. Because "Event" content type is reusable. So I didn't add anything to it.

Comment: I've just updated my answer

Comment: I want to use the typical Approval workflow. But I am not able to copy and modify the Approval workflow. How can I copy the workflow and use it as a list workflow?

Comment: I've just updated answer

Answer (score -1):

The same way you added the Name of Event

Inside the email you click on 'Add or Change Lookup'

Select the Data Source as Current Item

Then the fields you have created on the List should automatically populate the drop down next to Field From Source

Comment: NO it doesn't have the fields of my Calendar List.